# Ubuntu 16.04 sees but fails to print to Brother HL-L2300D

Tags: printing, raspberrypi, brother

I'm a noob, so please be as clear as you can be.

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on two Raspberry Pi 2s. I bought a Brother HL-L2300D Printer that has only the USB interface. I have spent a good fraction of two days trying to get it to print from the Pi's. It won't.

I've installed the driver, I've followed the instructions from Brother, and numerous web pages including the How-To Geek page about this using this model of Printer on a RPi. CUPS has no problem seeing the printer. LibreOffice can see it too. But the printer does nothing when the machines think they have succeeded in printing.

If I hook the printer to my Mac, it works fine, so there is no reason to think there is anything physically wrong. The cable works. The printer works. The RPi's see the printer.

What am I missing?

**[Update: Brother tells me that this printer is not supported on Raspberry Pi's. That is unacceptable given that the web information says Linux (and specifically Ubuntu) are supported, without any warning about RPi being an exception. But it does explain why I couldn't make it work.

Brother should provide a PPD file, which I believe would solve the problem. In the meantime, be warned. The Brother HLL2300d and RPi are not compatible, irrespective of Linux distribution.**

Thanks,

Bret

Answer (score 0):

I was just having troubles with my HP M1212nf MFP, similar to your problem. In my case when I went into Printers, Policies, I noticed that Enabled became unchecked. How? Who knows?

Did you manage to solve your problem in the meantime?

Comment: Nope. Can't find a way in. Ubuntu thinks it has printed successfully, but the printer does not spit anything out. Also, the blinking light that indicate data is arriving at the printer does not blink.

Comment: If you have a scanner with the printer, see if that is working. In my case simple scan made a scan but the printer wouldn't print because of the enable. Another thing which sometimes goes wrong is the printer IP changes. I understand from what you say that the printer queue is empty?

Comment: There is no scanner, and no ethernet. It's a simple printer with USB only. I keep emptying the queue. I have disabled and reenabled the printer in the CUPS interface several times. That's not the problem. The computer sees the printer, and the printer sees the computer. But when the computer thinks it has succeeded in printing, the printer does not react.

I'm beginning to suspect the driver is at fault.

Comment: I can only tell you what I did with my problem and hope there might be something similar. A driver does sound reasonable. I have all my computers running Ubuntu, so what I would do is try it on another computer - if the driver got loaded badly on your Raspberry. I know you said it works on your Mac, but we need to check a machine with the same OS.

Comment: I appreciate that, but the Ubuntu machines I have are duplicates of each other, and each has the same problem. I wonder if anyone has gotten a Brother HLL2300D working with Ubuntu, or an RPi or both.

Comment: See update of original post.

Comment: At least you know that you didn't do something wrong. Still, what a bummer.